# The last cell in UITableView always has the same height as the tallest cell in the table?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView that displays comments.  The last cell always has the same height as the tallest cell in the UITableView and I do not know why.  With reference to the image below, it can be seen that the height of the last custom object (LabelWithPadding) that holds the comment is the same height as the tallest custom object in the same table.  Please can someone advise?

```
class CommentOnPostTableView: UITableView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

var items: [Comment]?
var post: ResearchPost?
let cellIDB = "commentCellId"

init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableView.Style, sourceData: [Comment], postContent: ResearchPost) {
    super.init(frame: frame, style: style)
    items = sourceData
    post = postContent

    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self
    self.register(CommentTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIDB)
    //self.separatorStyle = .none
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}


/**Delegate functions*/
extension CommentOnPostTableView{

/***Number of cells*/
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let dataSource = items{
        return dataSource.count
    }else{
        return 0
    }
}


/***Create Cell*/
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let dataSource = items else{return UITableViewCell.init()}
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIDB, for: indexPath) as! CommentTableViewCell
    cell.dataObject = dataSource[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}



class CommentTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var commentLabel: LabelWithPadding!
var imgView: UIImageView = {
    let view = UIImageView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

var nameLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 11)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

    var dataObject: Comment?{
    didSet{
        if let data = dataObject{
            guard
                let image = data.imageOfCommentor,
                let name = data.name,
                let comment = data.comment else{return}

            imgView.image = image
            nameLabel.text = name

            let padding = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 3, left: 5, bottom: 3, right: 5)
            commentLabel = LabelWithPadding.init(frame: .zero, with: padding)
            commentLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            commentLabel.label.text = comment
            setupViews()
        }
    }
}

    ....

    // Auto layout constraints

    private func setupViews(){
    let c = contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide

    contentView.addSubview(imgView)
    contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(commentLabel)

    imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: c.topAnchor, constant: borderSpace).isActive = true
    imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: c.leadingAnchor, constant: borderSpace).isActive = true
    imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: c.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.08).isActive = true
    imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: c.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.08).isActive = true

    nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: c.topAnchor, constant: borderSpace).isActive = true
    nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    nameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: c.trailingAnchor, constant: -borderSpace).isActive = true

    commentLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: viewSpace).isActive = true
    commentLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    commentLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: c.trailingAnchor, constant: -borderSpace).isActive = true
    commentLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: c.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    commentLabel.label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
    commentLabel.label.numberOfLines = 0
    commentLabel.label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    commentLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 7
    commentLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
    commentLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.appGrayExtraLightGray
}
}
```

Custom Class:

```
class LabelWithPadding: UIView {

var padding: UIEdgeInsets!
let label: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()


init(frame: CGRect, with padding: UIEdgeInsets) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.padding = padding
    setupView()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


private func setupView(){
    self.addSubview(label)
    label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: padding.top).isActive = true
    label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -padding.bottom).isActive = true
    label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: padding.left).isActive = true
    label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding.bottom).isActive = true
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I couldn't find where you update constraints.

When you use `tableView.dequeueReusableCell`, you may get the old cell, so you should update old constraints (or remove old constratints and add new ones). You may read it in [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614891-dequeuereusablecell).

You should add variable to store old constraints:

```
var oldConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
```

And should deactivate old constraints and add new constraints in `setupView()`:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(oldConstraints)

let constraints = [
    imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: c.topAnchor, constant: borderSpace),
    imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: c.leadingAnchor, constant: borderSpace),
    imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: c.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.08),
    imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: c.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.08),
    nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: c.topAnchor, constant: borderSpace),
    nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.trailingAnchor, constant: 10),
    nameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: c.trailingAnchor, constant: -borderSpace),
    commentLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: viewSpace),
    commentLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.widthAnchor),
    commentLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: c.trailingAnchor, constant: -borderSpace),
    commentLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: c.bottomAnchor)
]
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)

oldConstraints = constraints
```

Also you shouldn't add subviews every time you update `dataObject` in `CommentTableViewCell`, because they could have already been added.

In conclusion, you should add subview to contentView just once and update the constraints every time you update `dataObject`. I gave you an example how to solve your issue.

---

You could also use [prepareForReuse()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse?language=occ) to prepare the cell for reuse:

> If a UITableViewCell object is reusable—that is, it has a reuse
>   identifier—this method is invoked just before the object is returned
>   from the UITableView method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:.